# scrbook chapter numbering (issue)

Tags: chapters, scrbook

I am writing my PhD thesis with the document class scrbook. It is a big project, so I am using a multi-file approach to include separate publications into a unique main file. Here is my issue: the heading of each chapter is numbered correctly until it arrives at 6, then chapters are numbered with letters (A,B,C,..). I have no idea where the issue could be. Here is the code I am using

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt, a4paper, footinclude=true, headinclude=true, cleardoublepage=empty]{scrbook}
\let\listoftables\relax
\let\listoffigures\relax
\usepackage[linedheaders,parts,pdfspacing,dottedtoc]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{acronym}

\usepackage[a4paper, hmargin={2.8cm, 2.8cm}, vmargin={2.5cm, 2.5cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{eso-pic} % \AddToShipoutPicture
\usepackage{graphicx} % \includegraphics
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{mathtools}  
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{array,multirow,bigdelim}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{braket}




\renewcommand*{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}


\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2.0}
\def\signed #1{{\leavevmode\unskip\nobreak\hfil\penalty50\hskip2em
  \hbox{}\nobreak\hfil(#1)%
    \parfillskip=0pt \finalhyphendemerits=0 \endgraf}}

    \newsavebox\mybox
    \newenvironment{aquote}[1]
      {\savebox\mybox{#1}\begin{quote}}
          {\signed{\usebox\mybox}\end{quote}}




\begin{document} 

\pagenumbering{roman}
\AddToShipoutPicture*{\put(0,0){\includegraphics*[viewport=0 0 700 600]{\ColourPDF}}}
\AddToShipoutPicture*{\put(0,602){\includegraphics*[viewport=0 600 700 1600]{\ColourPDF}}}
\AddToShipoutPicture*{\put(0,0){\includegraphics*{\TitlePDF}}}

\clearpage\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}

\newpage

\include{FrontBackMatter/abstract}

\include{FrontBackMatter/Preface}

\include{FrontBackMatter/reprints}

\include{FrontBackMatter/acknowledgements}



\include{FrontBackMatter/contents}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\part{Introduction}\label{part:I}
\include{introduction/motivation}
\include{introduction/outline}
\include{introduction/introduction}


\part{Bla bla}\label{part:II}
\include{papers/1}
\include{papers/2}
\include{papers/3}
\include{papers/4}

\part{Bla- bla more}\label{part:III}
\include{papers/5}


\part{Bla-bla even more}\label{part:IV}
\include{papers/6}

\part{Conclusion and Future Work}\label{part:V}

\include{conclusion/conclusion}

\include{conclusion/futurework}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Does the 5th paper, by any chance, include an appendix?

Comment: It is not a matter of content of files, since if I re-order papers with "\include" the issue remains. It looks as if my code can only count till "6", then it has to switch to letters for headings of chapters....

Comment: The only commands I can think of that might make such a change are `\appendix` or `\backmatter`.  None of the packages listed should have that effect, although you might look into `classicthesis` (which I've never explored).  You can try using brute force -- reset the chapter counter to 0 and repeat the command to reset it to arabic just before the chapter where it changes -- but that's not very satisfying.

Comment: Thanks Barbara, you were right! There was exactly a \backmatter comment: once removed, everything was fine, thanks again :)

Comment: Whew!  A wild guess comes through again.  Do you mind if I vote to close the question?  Even though this problem might happen again, the question isn't phrased in such a way that it's likely to be easy to recover.  (I'll add a "complimentary" answer anyhow.)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem was caused by an errant `\backmatter` in an included file.  In the absence of a detailed example, this question isn't likely to be found by others who might have a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

Guessing possible reasons that might cause the chapter number to be reset and turn to "numbering" by letters of the alphabet, the only two I could think of were `\appendix` and `\backmatter`.

The author searched the included files and found an errant `\backmatter`, and its removal got rid of the problem.